LoRa with Step Up MT3608
I'm having trouble with a problem that I don't know how to investigate anymore. I created a board based on the ESP32 with LoRa (915 MHz) and a step up (MT3608) to use in 4-20 mA current sensors.
The attached schematic shows a simplified version without the buttons, capacitor and pull resistors, but I guarantee that the ESP32 works completely normally.
The LoRa module also works well, it is capable of sending and receiving data.
The step up also works well, converting the 8V4 input to 24V correctly.
The step up circuit is driven by a pair of MOSFETs, allowing the ESP32 to turn the step up on and off whenever it wants.
The problem is the following: When the step up turns on, the LoRa stops working correctly. When the step up is turned off, the LoRa returns to working normally. I don't believe that the cause is a voltage drop because I've already measured it and didn't notice any drop. I didn't include a schematic, but in practice I used a 220 µF electrolytic capacitor to power the Lora.
Is it some kind of noise from the step-up? Is there a way to fix it? The board has already been manufactured, is it possible to make some adjustments/jumpers and reuse the board?
I have another board that is very similar but has a step-down (MP1584) and the exact same thing happens.
I have 16 years of experience as a backend, web and mobile application developer but I have recently been studying hardware and embedded development on my own. Please be understanding and polite.
I would really appreciate any help you can give.

I am placing below the real and complete schematic of the board, as well as the layout and a 3D of the final board. I am using the following inductor:
https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Power-Inductors_SXN-Shun-Xiang-Nuo-Elec-SMDRH105R-220MT_C10165.html




Noise is certainly possible. Are you using a shielded inductor? I think we'd have to see your PCB layout to make useful suggestions.

Hello! I've edited the post to include details of the board layout.

Okay. I'm going to let others take a swing at this for now (really late here), but I think you've provided the needed information. Your inductor is shielded.

The layout seams to be designed to produce maximum EMI noise. Is there a ground plane, we just don't see, or is GND only distibuted via these thin tracks?

@Jens Do you mean I designed the layout to produce maximum EMI noise?

what do you mean by "stops working correctly"? Does it still respond to the ESP but just suck at transcieving or does it not appear to be connected anymore? Also, many cheap DC-DC converters cause a large current spike when "plugged in", which could be glitching the LoRa module; try a linear/LDO and see if the fault still occurs, and if so, upgrade the DC-DC.

@dandavis When I turn on the step up circuit, LoRa still responds to the ESP32 and occasionally even sends a packet or two. I understand that the step up can cause a current spike when turning on but then it should stabilize, right? After a few seconds with the step up turned on, I reconnect to LoRa to try to normalize the sending of packets but without success. LoRa responds correctly to the ESP32 but fails to send 95% of the packets, it only normalizes when I turn off the step up circuit. Remember that I am not adding any load to the step up output.

I have marked the curent path during the active phase of the switch inside the boost converter with a gree track.
To reduce the EMI radiation it is important to keep the ocupied area small. This could be improved here by optimized component placement, but wider tracks would also lower unwanted inductance on this path.

I did the same for the other phase, where the inductor charges the output capacitor.
This current path looks really bad, a large area is covered and the tracks form a winding with two turns.
Most of the EMI ringing is generated when the IC turns off the inductor current and this RF energy will be radiated by this large loop.
A direct wire from D2 to C5 would shorten the loop drastically and could be a first aid. I would also add a thick extra GND wire between C3 and C5.
Adding a R/C snubber network between the SW pin of the IC and GND will further reduce the EMI.
In the datasheet of the MT3608 you can find a chapter Layout Consideration with more useful hints. These considerations are very important at a switching frequency of 1.2 MHz.

